# Howto share NetBeans profile across 3 computers and 4 separate OS's (Windows and Linux)?

Tags: netbeans

I use 3 different computers and 4 separate OS's (Windows and Linux) and want to take the pain out of making sure plugins are installed correctly, formatting settings are the same, other settings are the same, etc. I don't want to copy them.

Sharing across multiple windows installations is easy, I just need to set the --userdir switch to the location. However one of the OS's is Ubuntu linux, and from [this post](http://www.mentby.com/Group/netbeans/how-can-i-share-netbeans-profile-netbeans-between-linux-and-windows.html), it looks like its not going to work.

I heavily use both Windows and Linux for development, so this is an issue. What can I do to make the profile cross compatible? Better yet, is there a plugin that does this automatically?

Comment: I would love to know if this is possible too.

Comment: @Toby Wow, I completely forgot about this question. I'll write my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been doing this for quite some time now. Basically here's how I did it

- I have a `.netbeans` folder on my portable hard drive which contains the profile
- Each machine has their own netbeans installation due to performance issues. All I do is modify the `etc/netbeans.conf` configuration file and set it to the path thats for that machine (remember that the drive mounts on different letters and locations)